# Responsive Web Design - switching between tabular and compact layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

When the viewer has a wide enough window (desktop/tablet) I want to use a tabular layout for my information:

[image]

On narrower windows (e.g smartphone) I want a more compact layout

[image]

I want to achieve this layout-change using CSS without any change in HTML

My HTML uses simple `<h2>` and `<p>` elements for the headings and content.

I've played around with CSS `float:left` and `display:inline` but found it difficult to achieve what I want.

What is the **simplest** way to achieve this in CSS while adhering to "responsive design" and "mobile-first" principles?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with.

The compact layout is close to the default display for `<h2>` and `<p>` and is the default layout with this CSS - so "mobile first".

A media selector is used to modify the layout for devices where the window is wider.

`float: left` is used to allow the headings to line-up vertically with the following text.

The top and bottom margins are set to zero on the headings so that headings with a single line of associated content don't interfere with each other causing a staggerred layout.

`margin-left: 13em` is used to keep the content clear of the headings and to produce a visual representation similar to what would be expected if the HTML had used a `<table>`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Test folding</title>
    <style>
      h2 { 
        font-size: 100%; 
        font-weight: bold; 
      }
      p { 
        margin-left: 1em; 
      }

      @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
        h2 { 
          margin-top: 0;
          margin-bottom: 0;
          float:left;
        }
        p {
          margin-left: 13em;
          margin-top: 0;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test folding</h1>

    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p>Dolor Sit amet</p>

    <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
    <p>Sit amet consectetur</p>

    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p>Dolor Sit amet  consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
      incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
    </p>
    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
      commodo consequat. 
    </p>
    <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
      velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
      occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
      mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>

    <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
    <p>Sit amet  consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
      incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
      commodo consequat. 
    </p>
    <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
      velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
      occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
      mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>

  </body>
</html>
```